# fill ant design Table with data from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm new in reactJS I stack in this problem :
I have to fill the table with data from API

- the problem: I can fill the table only with the const variable, not in the useEffect function.

**the code:**

```
function CandidaturesList() {
  const [candidatures , setCandidatures]=useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
      try {

        
        const response = /*some code to get data*/
        setCandidatures(response);
        
      } catch (error) {
        // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
        alert(
          `Failed to load  `,
        );
        console.error(error);
      } 
    }
    fetchData();

  },[candidatures]);
  

  // project table start
  const project = [
    {
      title: "COMPANIES",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "32%",
    },
    {
      title: "JOB TITLE",
      dataIndex: "jobtitle",
    },
    {
      title: "DECISION",
      dataIndex: "decision",
    },

  ];
  const candidature = [
    {
      key: "1",

      name: (
        <>
          <div className="avatar-info">
            <Title level={5}>Spotify Version</Title>
          </div>
        </>
      ),
      jobtitle: (
        <>
          <div className="semibold">Manager</div>
        </>
      ),
      decision: (
        <>
          <div className="ant-progress-project">
            <Tag icon={<CheckCircleOutlined />} color="#87d068">
              Valid
            </Tag>
          </div>
        </>
      ),
    },

    {
      key: "2",
      name: (
        <>
          <div className="avatar-info">
            <Title level={5}>Progress Track</Title>
          </div>
        </>
      ),
      jobtitle: (
        <>
          <div className="semibold">Developer full stack</div>
        </>
      ),
      decision: (
        <>
          <div className="ant-progress-project">
            <Tag icon={<SyncOutlined spin />} color="#108ee9">
              Processing
            </Tag>
          </div>
        </>
      ),
    },
]
return (
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <Table
            columns={project}
            dataSource={candidature}
            pagination={false}
            className="ant-border-space"
          />
        </div>
);}
```

So the const candidature is just having a fake data
and the candidatures state is having the real data to put in the table
the question is: how can I map the "candidatures" state to put the data in the table with the same style as the "const candidature" or how can I put the data of "candidatures" in this const?
One thing to note here is that candidatures state variable is array of objects, like

````
{[titre_poste: 'developeur full stack', nomCompagnie: 'nomCompagnie',decision: "none",id: "2"],[ ... ] }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, i see that `candidatures` is your `data` and `projects` is your table `schema`
you shouldn't put `html` within your `data` array, you should instead use the `render` key within your `schema` array which in your case is `projects`.

it should look something like this

```
// project table start
  const project = [
    {
      title: "COMPANIES",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "32%",
      render: text => (
          <div className="avatar-info">
            <Title level={5}>{text}</Title>
          </div>
      )
    }
  ]

  const candidature = [
    {
      key: "1",
      name: "Some string value"
    }
]
```

secondly, in your `useEffect` function, you have created a recursion via your dependency of `candidatures`.
You are listening for changes in `candidatures` while upon every change you trigger an api call which changes the `candidatures` state which in turn again triggers the useEffect call.

to prevent this, remove `candidatures` as useEffect dependency.